# How do I create binned factor variables from a continuous variable, with custom breaks?

Tags: r

I have a vector that looks like this:

```
dataset <- c(4,7,9,1,10,15,18,19,3,16,10,16,12,22,2,23,16,17)
```

I would like to create four dummy categories, in which I bin the continuous dataset by custom breaks . .. for example: 1:4, 5:9, 10:17, 18:23.

The output dummy categories would have the same length as the original continuous vector (18 in this case), but now each binned dummy variable would just contain a 1 or a 0.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `cut`:

```
data.frame(dataset, bin=cut(dataset, c(1,4,9,17,23), include.lowest=TRUE))
```

Comment: To get from `cut` to dummy variables (which is what the OP asked for), try `model.matrix(~bin-1,data=dataset)`

Answer (score 9):

I agree with Joshua that `cut` is what most people would think of for this task. I don't happen to like its defaults, preferring to have left-closed intervals and it's a minor pain to set that up correctly with `cut` (although it can be done. Fortunately for my feeble brain, Frank Harrell has designed a `cut2` function in his Hmisc package whose defaults I prefer. A third alternative is to use `findInterval` which is especially suited for problems where you wnat to use the result as an index to another extractions or selection process. Its results are roughly what you would get if you applied `as.numeric` to the results of `cut`:

```
require(Hmisc)
cut2(dataset, c(1,4,9,17,23) )
 [1] [ 4, 9) [ 4, 9) [ 9,17) [ 1, 4) [ 9,17) [ 9,17) [17,23] [17,23] [ 1, 4) [ 9,17)
[11] [ 9,17) [ 9,17) [ 9,17) [17,23] [ 1, 4) [17,23] [ 9,17) [17,23]
```

(Notice that `findInterval` will use the upper bound as the closed end to form an extra interval unless you replace the maximum with `Inf` , a reserved word for infinity in R.)

```
findInterval(dataset, c( c(1,4,9,17,23) ) )
 [1] 2 2 3 1 3 3 4 4 1 3 3 3 3 4 1 5 3 4
as.numeric( cut(dataset, c(1,4,9,17,Inf), include.lowest=TRUE))
 [1] 1 2 2 1 3 3 4 4 1 3 3 3 3 4 1 4 3 3
as.numeric( cut(dataset, c(1,4,9,17,23), include.lowest=TRUE))
 [1] 1 2 2 1 3 3 4 4 1 3 3 3 3 4 1 4 3 3
```